# Toggle JQuery dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop down menu that has different heights based on a selection of classes - one-row, two-row, three-row.

The main content of the site also animates down depending on these classes.

I have also implemented a function that makes the menu reset if the user clicks outside of it.

Everything is working as required other than the fact the I cannot use 'toggleClass' to make the menu close if the link is clicked again.

Can any of you JQuery gurus help me out here?

```
// ============================================================
//
//  DROP DOWN MENU
//
// ============================================================
$('.submenu-toggle').on('click', function (e) {

    // Reset all other drop downs and icons
    $('.submenu').removeClass('drop-down');
    $('.submenu-toggle').find('.fa-angle-down').removeClass('rotate');

    // Drop down this menu
    $(this).find('.submenu').addClass('drop-down');

    // Rotate the icon
    $(this).find('.fa-angle-down').addClass('rotate');

    // Drop the main content wrapper down depending on the 
    // number of rows in the drop-down menu
    if ($(this).find('.submenu').hasClass('one-row')) {
        $('.content-wrapper').addClass('one-row-drop-down');
        $('.content-wrapper').removeClass('two-row-drop-down three-row-drop-down four-row-drop-down');
    } 
    if ($(this).find('.submenu').hasClass('two-row')) {
        $('.content-wrapper').addClass('two-row-drop-down');
        $('.content-wrapper').removeClass('one-row-drop-down three-row-drop-down four-row-drop-down');
    }
    if ($(this).find('.submenu').hasClass('three-row')) {
        $('.content-wrapper').addClass('three-row-drop-down');
        $('.content-wrapper').removeClass('one-row-drop-down two-row-drop-down four-row-drop-down');
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
});


// Reset dropdowns and reset icon on click outside
$(document).on('click', function () {
    $('.submenu').removeClass('drop-down');
    $('.submenu-toggle').find('.fa-angle-down').removeClass('rotate');
    $('.content-wrapper').removeClass('one-row-drop-down two-row-drop-down three-row-drop-down');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery toggle

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

See here some examples http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#entry-examples

```
$( "#foo" ).toggle( display );
```

is equivalent to:

```
if ( display === true ) {
  $( "#foo" ).show();
} else if ( display === false ) {
  $( "#foo" ).hide();
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for  your answer. The only issue is that I need to toggle a class but toggleClass doesn't work